# How to use AngularJS on a single page in my Grails app, and regular JS on others?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails

I've spent a few hours on this now and I cannot crack it.

I'm trying to implement a great AngularJS example I found online into my app, while my front end up to now is fully normal JS.

I have installed the pipeline plugin and put the files in the respective folders:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPj4P.png

AngularJS seems to be loading in correctly and in the right order, however in the dev tools it does say 'compile=false' after the js file name? 
See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/erN3x.png

I tried to redirect to the new AngularJS page when I click into one of my current views, I thought that the following code was going to do so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider
  .when('/view', {
      templateUrl: 'assets/index.html'
  })
```

So is it possible to use both AngularJS and regular JS in my application?
And if so, how do I go about moving from a JS to an AngularJS page?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to url http://localhost:8080/#/view But if you enable html5Mode then to view it simply go to http://localhost:8080/view